# CentOS7 - Chef(open source) setup error

Tags: chef, centos7

Been wrestling with setting up a chef-server at the moment on CentOS7. chef-admin seems to be doing fine.

I "(1) sudo wget https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-server-11.1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm and (2) sudo rpm -Uvh chef-server-11.1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm" per standard procedure I always do.

Those ran smoothly but at "sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure"

getting following output errors. I verified I have openSSL and 'build-essential' installed.

```
Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: chef-server::default
  * directory[/etc/chef-server] action create (up to date)
[2015-04-03T18:23:23-07:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/chef-server/chef-server-webui/etc] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-04-03T18:23:23-07:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/chef-server/chef-server-webui/etc]: /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/chef-server-webui.rb:31:in `block in from_file'
[2015-04-03T18:23:23-07:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/chef-server/chef-server-webui/etc]: /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/definitions/unicorn_config.rb:21:in `block in from_file'
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..+++
.......................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Converging 212 resources
  * directory[/etc/chef-server] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: chef-server::users
  * user[chef_server] action create (up to date)
  * group[chef_server] action create (up to date)
Recipe: chef-server::default
  * directory[/etc/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/chef-server] action create (up to date)
Recipe: runit::upstart
  * execute[initctl stop opscode-runsvdir] action run (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[/etc/init/opscode-runsvdir.conf] action delete (up to date)
  * cookbook_file[/etc/init/chef-server-runsvdir.conf] action create
    * Parent directory /etc/init does not exist.
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file[/etc/init/chef-server-runsvdir.conf]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist
Running handlers:
[2015-04-03T18:23:23-07:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2015-04-03T18:23:23-07:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-04-03T18:23:23-07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 7.083390475 seconds
[2015-04-03T18:23:24-07:00] ERROR: cookbook_file[/etc/init/chef-server-runsvdir.conf] (runit::upstart line 29) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist: Parent directory /etc/init does not exist.
[2015-04-03T18:23:24-07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
$
```

Thanks.

Comment: You installed the package for CentOS 6, which has a different init system than CentOS 7.

Comment: aahhh.. no wonder the usual setup didn't work. I do recall last setup was on 6. Is there any way around this? Thank you for the comment.

Comment: https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/runit/issues/74 Looks like chef doesn't officially support RHEL/CentOS 7, which is pretty unfortunate since it's nearly a year old.

Comment: I'll downgrade to 6. Oh well. Do you want to post an answer so that I can give you credit? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.centos.org/Download is your friend.
Chef will not work on 7.

It's a good practice to keep an older version once a while in case packages don't upgrade for 7 or any other new version.